# Can't manage to make a list out of a custom class on Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart

i'm learning Flutter by following a 3yo guide by The Net Ninja, stuck on the custom classes part. I can't manage to output info from a list with a custom class. Can anyone help with an explaination please?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'quote.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(
  home: QuoteList(),
));

class QuoteList extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuoteList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QuoteList> createState() => _QuoteListState();
}

class _QuoteListState extends State<QuoteList> {
  List<Quote> quotes = [
    Quote(author: 'Oscar Wilde', text: 'Be yourself; everyone else is already taken'),
    Quote(author: 'Oscar Wilde', text: 'I have nothing to declare except my genius'),
    Quote(author: 'Oscar Wilde', text: 'The truth is rarely pure and never simple')
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Awesome Quotes'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        itemCount: quotes.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          return Center(child: Text('${quotes.author} - ${quotes.text}'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried this piece given to me by my friend, didn't work out.

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic» quote = [
{'author': 'Osc...', 'text': "aaa"},
{'author': 'Osc...', 'text': "aaa"}
];
```

Comment: You need to access the `quotes` list using the `index`. Like `${quotes[index].author}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the quote inside your `List<Quote> quotes`.
You can do it by accessing the index:

```dart
final quote = quotes[index];
```

Don't forget to change the `Text`:

```dart
Text('${quotes.author} - ${quotes.text}')
```

to

```dart
Text('${quote.author} - ${quote.text}')
```

Here is the full example:

```dart
ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        itemCount: quotes.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
          final quote = quotes[index];
          return Center(child: Text('${quote.author} - ${quote.text}'));
        },
      )
```

Comment: thanks, that actually helped, but for some reason this appears when i try to reload: 
type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Quote>' of 'function result'

Comment: Where do you get it?

Comment: mid compiling, the console doesn't link to the actual source of the issue

Comment: Nevermind, i just needed to restart hot reload because i changed some data, now it works